# Developing an appropriate volatility variable to predict stock returns based on past month

Tags: regression, forecasting, finance

I am doing a project about the predictability of stock returns. I am using following regression model:
\begin{equation} r_{t} = \alpha+\beta X_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t},
\end{equation}
where $r_{t}$ is the stock return in month ${t}$, $\beta$ is a slope of regression line, $X_{t-1}$ is the predictor of stock returns at month ${t}-1$, $\alpha$ is a constant and $\epsilon_{t}$ is the error term.

I have data set on monthly returns for 1764 months and I am trying to develop past month volatility as the predicting variable.

I tried to do it by following method:

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{monthly}=\sqrt{(r_i-\overline{\mu})^2}
\end{equation}
where $r_t$ is monthly stock return at the time $t$ and $\overline{\mu}$ is the average stock return defined as:
\begin{equation}
\overline{\mu}=\frac{1}{1764}\sum_{i=1}^{1764} r_i.
\end{equation}

However, I am not sure if this is done correctly as I can't find any sources on exactly this issue.

Thank you very much in advance for the help

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that $\sqrt{(r_i-\overline{\mu})^2}=|r_i-\overline{\mu}|$?

Comment: thank you very much for this clarification

Comment: If you only have monthly data, not something more frequent, then you may consider a GARCH-in-mean / GARCH-M model [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity#GARCH-M). The problem is, the model has contemporaneous variance in the mean equation rather than past variance. I wonder if there is a way around that so as to trick the standard estimation routines for GARCH-M into estimating the model with a lagged variance in the mean equation. Alternatively, you could estimate volatility first using some sort of GARCH model and use the estimate.

Comment: Thank you, Richard. Do you have any advice for a simple model/formula, as I am not very advanced in this topic.

Comment: Do you want to do this by hand, or are you comfortable using built-in functions in R or Python or your favourite statistical package? In R, I would recommend the `rugarch` package with functions `ugarchspec` and `ugarchfit` for fitting GARCH models.

Comment: I can only use Stata. I was thinking about calculating 12-month gliding average return, then calculating volatility by the formula u gave me (absolute value of stock return - average return). Lastly, computing a regression, with stock return (dependent variable) and last month volatility as a predictor. Would something like that be reasable?

Comment: I have also daily data that i can use, would this be helpful to generate monthly volatility variable?

Comment: Stata can do GARCH models too, if anything. Daily data helps. You could use the so-called *realized volatility* estimated from daily data for each month, that may be a more accurate estimate than what a GARCH model could offer. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realized_variance) for a brief intro.